# WebApi Json Self referencing loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework, json.net

I am having a horrible time solving this error in my ASP.NET WebApi project (full DotNet, not Core):

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>Self referencing loop detected for property 'Server' with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Server_8AB873452FD27AADAE6B91C89AF500FFD407544E56422B394D3E2B8AC1524157'. Path 'Server_Hardware_Current[0]'.</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException</ExceptionType>
     <StackTrace>   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
               at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)
               at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
               at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
               at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
               at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
               at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
               at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
               at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
               at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
               at System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult`1.Serialize()
               at System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult`1.Execute()
               at System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult`1.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
               at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
               at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
               at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
               at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
               at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
               at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
     </StackTrace>
</Error>
```

I have to add and strongly stress that I am a noob in c#.
If you need more information, please tell me what exactly you need and if you want me to put core in a file, please tell me the file name ;)

**About my project:**

I am trying to create a client / server solution that will deploy an agent on a target server / client and have it's hardware and software sent to a central database, kind of like every software deployment software does.
The agent itself can read the desired information from the system, so I am now trying to create the WebApi that will accept the result and provile a communication endpoint for the agent as well as some sort of console to see the information and do different kind of assessment (are my systems up to date? which software is installed where and so on).

**Used Software and Packages**

I am running Visual Studio 2017 community

Nuget packages:

- The default WebApi packages (Inclused Newtonsoft.Json)
- Entity Framework 6, also have created a model EDMX file which looks
  quite correct to me
- Enterprise Library for logging

**The controller code part**

```
        public IHttpActionResult GetSingleServer(int id)
    {

        // using (KysoHostDbContext ServersDbContext = new KysoHostDbContext())
        // {
            KysoHostDbContext ServersDbContext = new KysoHostDbContext();
        //ServersDbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        //ServersDbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;


        var returnobject = ServersDbContext.Servers.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ServerId == id);
           // .Include(ServersDbContext.Servers.FirstOrDefault().Server_OS_Current.ToString());


            if ((returnobject.Equals(null)))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(returnobject);
            }
        // }

    }
```

**The Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace KysoWebApi.Models
{
public partial class Servers
{
    public Servers()
    {
        ServerHardwareCurrent = new HashSet<ServerHardwareCurrent>();
        ServerHardwareHistory = new HashSet<ServerHardwareHistory>();
        ServerOsCurrent = new HashSet<ServerOsCurrent>();
        ServerOsHistory = new HashSet<ServerOsHistory>();
        ServerWinFeaturesCurrent = new HashSet<ServerWinFeaturesCurrent>();
        ServerWinFeaturesHistory = new HashSet<ServerWinFeaturesHistory>();
        ServerWinInstalledSoftwareCurrent = new HashSet<ServerWinInstalledSoftwareCurrent>();
        ServerWinInstalledSoftwareHistory = new HashSet<ServerWinInstalledSoftwareHistory>();
        ServerWinRolesCurrent = new HashSet<ServerWinRolesCurrent>();
        ServerWinRolesHistory = new HashSet<ServerWinRolesHistory>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ServerId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    public string AgentGuid { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Server")]
    public ICollection<ServerHardwareCurrent> ServerHardwareCurrent { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Server")]
    public ICollection<ServerHardwareHistory> ServerHardwareHistory { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Server")]
    public ICollection<ServerOsCurrent> ServerOsCurrent { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Server")]
    public ICollection<ServerOsHistory> ServerOsHistory { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Server")]
    public ICollection<ServerWinFeaturesCurrent> ServerWinFeaturesCurrent { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Server")]
    public ICollection<ServerWinFeaturesHistory> ServerWinFeaturesHistory { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Server")]
    public ICollection<ServerWinInstalledSoftwareCurrent> ServerWinInstalledSoftwareCurrent { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Server")]
    public ICollection<ServerWinInstalledSoftwareHistory> ServerWinInstalledSoftwareHistory { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Server")]
    public ICollection<ServerWinRolesCurrent> ServerWinRolesCurrent { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Server")]
    public ICollection<ServerWinRolesHistory> ServerWinRolesHistory { get; set; }
   }
}
```

**What I have tried already**

I have been reading a log and tried lots of different solutions, but strangely, none of them worked for me. because of that I guess it's some sort of very stupid newbie mistake -.-
Of course, I have tried all of those solutions (now commented out) individually.

- Global.asax

  ```
          /*
      var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
      json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =
          Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
          */



      /*
      HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

      config.Formatters.JsonFormatter
                  .SerializerSettings
                  .ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
      */

      /*
      JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
      {
          Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
          ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
      };
      */
  ```
- WebApiConfig.cs

  ```
      /*
      config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling
      = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
      */


      /*
      config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling
      = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
      config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling
      = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
      */

      /*
       * var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
      json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
      */
  ```
- ServerController.cs

As you have probably seen in the controller code, I have tried to disable lazy loading explicitly, as my model included the virtual directive. As removing it did not help I tried to disable lazy loading, which still resulted in the same error.
Only when I disable ProxyCreation, I get a result, but that only includes the SQL data from within the Servers table and not all child objects, which I want to have.
That might not be necessary all the time, but please bear with me as I am will need it later on anyhow.

I also tried to use something like using .Include but I failed to get it working.
My feeling is that:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetSingleServer(int id)
```

might be an issue, but then I cannot use

```
return NotFound();
```

or:

```
return Json(returnobject);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Also, thanks in advance for anybody taking the time to read all this :)

---

**Update 1**

I tried: 
`      public IHttpActionResult GetSingleServer(int id)
        {

```
        // using (KysoHostDbContext ServersDbContext = new KysoHostDbContext())
        // {
            KysoHostDbContext ServersDbContext = new KysoHostDbContext();
        // ServersDbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        ServersDbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;


        var returnobject = ServersDbContext.Servers.Include("ServerHardwareCurrent")
                .Where(a => a.ServerId == id);
           // .Include(ServersDbContext.Servers.FirstOrDefault().Server_OS_Current.ToString());


            if ((returnobject.Equals(null)))
            {
                ServersDbContext.Dispose();
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
            ServersDbContext.Dispose();
            return Json(returnobject);
            }
        // }

    }`
```

Which gives me:

```
<ExceptionMessage>The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1
```

I explicitely have lazy loading disabled but it still tries to lazy load?

Same result if I try to move it around: var returnobject = ServersDbContext.Servers.Where(a => a.ServerId == id).Include("ServerHardwareCurrent");

This is driving me nuts. why does it lazy load all the time even when I tell it not to? :/

Comment: Does any of the classes that are named like `Server***Current` or `Server***History` have a reference to the `Servers` class?

Comment: Hi Dido. Actually I did not create separate classes for them, because the server's current software/hardware or it's former software/hardware is related to the server itself. Was that wrong? 
Inside the database those tables all have the ServerID as a foreign key to the ServerID in the Servers table. So just a one way relation. The model created by EF picked that up, but added additional navigation properties to those tables on the Servers table. I have read, that this might have generated the reference loop, but I am not sure if I actually should delete them.

Comment: I just realized, that when I disable LazyLoading, the error goes away but the child objects are **not** beeing displayed, and I need them :/

Comment: My guess is that you're not loading the related entities. [Take a look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx) and see how you can load them explicitly.

Comment: As I cannot write a big enough comment I have updated my question with the results

Comment: Ok, two things. First, disabling lazy loading doesn't automatically make your query eager - it just means that if you forgot to load an entity and you're trying to access it, EF won't generate SQL and do a query to get it for you. Second, materialize your query. Put a `.ToList()` after your `Where()` clause.

Comment: Aha! I found a solution to the "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed" problem. Sadly, .ToList() was already there and didn't help. It seems the Json converter wants to check for related entities and then wants to load them which triggers lazy loading. But, as you said: With lazy loading disabled, it won't load the related entities if I don't explicitly tell it to. As this is the case with the list of servers, I just disabled lazy loading within the using statement and the list loads fine, containing only the properties that are in the servers table. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding my relation loop problem, I figured out that if I delete the navigation properties of all tables related to the servers table, it works. I have to leave them at the servers table, though. That doesn't actually solve the problem of Json not caring about me telling it to ignore the loop , but it removes the loop and at least my code works. Is this an acceptable way to go? I wonder, because I mess with the entity framework's model and I think if EF generates that model, then it should work? Or maybe just not with the json converter..

Answer (score 0):

As there are no more comments, this was my solution. Please take it with a grain of salt:

Regarding my relation loop problem, I figured out that if I delete the navigation properties of all tables related to the servers table, it works. I have to leave them at the servers table, though. That doesn't actually solve the problem of Json not caring about me telling it to ignore the loop , but it removes the loop and at least my code works.